# How to tile a tensor in this way? (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tile

Origin tensor:

```
a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

I want tensor in this way:

```
result = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[7,8,9],[7,8,9]]
```

Using tile api seems not suitable, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`tf.repeat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/repeat).

```
tf.repeat(a, repeats=3, axis=0)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(9, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [7, 8, 9]])>
```